# Dynamic Distribution Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, concurrency

I've been racking my brain all morning trying to come up with the following algorithm, this is especially frustrating because I'm sure that it's possible.

What I need is a class that has a function that returns `boolean`.  It can be called any number of times and will return true `XX%` of the time.  This CANNOT be a random distribution, for example:

If the ratio `X` is set to `0.6` and the function is called `100` times, we need to return exactly `60` true results.  In which order "left overs" are used doesn't matter, for example: if the function was called `99` times it would be OK to return either `59` or `60` true values.

The trick here is that the ratio needs to be variable.

For some setup, I'm working in a multi threaded environment so I'm keeping my "hitNumber" variable in an `AtomicLong` in order to avoid `synchronization` issues.

Thanks!

Comment: What is this boolean result testing for? Or is it just returning a semi-randomized result?

Comment: Fill a boolean array with `X` true values. Shuffle. Retrieve in order.

Comment: hah.  I was just typing out what @Geobits just recommended, but he beat me to it

Comment: So far I've tried....
if((hitCount % 100) > (ratio * 100))

The problem is, if the ratio is 60, the first 60 hits will all be true and the next 40 will all be false.  This doesn't work if you only get 65 hits.

Comment: @MattKlooster add what you've tried to your question as a code block so everybody can look at it.

Comment: What do you mean with "exactly 60 true results"? Does it mean, it has to return exactly 30 times true if called 50 times? So 15x true for 25 calls = 3x true for 5 calls? That's not random any more.

Comment: @Geobits, that assumes you have prior knowledge of the number of calls to the function...(?)

Comment: @Geobits I would need something more dynamic, I can't know how many hits there will be.  (I'm hoping less than Long.MAX_VALUE)

Comment: @MattKlooster just reshuffle your array when you reach the end of it, rinse, and repeat

Comment: True, but it's hard to know exactly what you want. Ben's answer works, but it throws all element of randomness out the window.

Comment: @StormeHawke reshuffling would mean random meaning that we can't guarantee that at any given time the ratio would be true.  I'm actually leaning towards Ben's answer.  Surprisingly super simple I may have been over thinking this one.

Comment: @Geobits, the OP clearly says that it cannot be a random distribution...

Comment: @Geobits this is good thing actually, I don't really want any element of randomness.

Comment: @MattKlooster Ah, then go with that. I read it as "a non-random distribution in a random order".

Comment: Yep, feeling pretty dumb for not thinking of that on my own now.  Just waiting to be able to accept the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you want is to maintain the overall percentage, just keep track of the percentage so far (probably as an explicit rational), and return `true` if you're under the target percentage, or `false` if you're over it.

Answer (score 3):

To build on Ben's answer, you can maintain static class variables to keep track of past function calls. Something like:

```
bool myFunc( float true_percentage ) {

  count++; // where count and count_true are class static variables initialized to zero.

  if ( float( count_true ) / count >= true_percentage )
    return false;

  count_true++;
  return true;

}
```

Comment: This looks like C/C++ code a lot more than Java. ;) Java doesn't support local static variables. It'd be better to store the two counts as non-static instance variables.

Comment: Yes sorry, missed the tag. I have changed them to class static variables.

Answer (score 3):

Your criterion that it can't be random is pretty ill-defined.  I suppose you mean that the quantity T/(T+F) is as close to the ratio as integer T and F will allow.

So you'll end up with something like this:

```
class TrueFalseGenerator {

  final double ratio;
  long nTrue, nFalse;

  TrueFalseGenerator(double ratio) {
    this.ratio = ratio;
    nTrue = nFalse = 0;
  }

  synchronized boolean next() {
    long den = nTrue + nFalse;
    if (den == 0 || (double)nTrue / den < ratio) {
      nTrue++;
      return true;
    } else {
      nFalse++;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This version uses only integer arithmetic and doesn't need any counter:

```
public class Distribution {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
    private int error;

    public Distribution(int numerator, int denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public synchronized boolean next() {
        error += numerator;
        if (error >= denominator) {
            error %= denominator;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Distribution dist = new Distribution(6, 10); // 6 trues out of 10
dist.next(); // get next bool
```

Comment: "doesn't need any counter" you're using a counter

Comment: No, I'm just calculating an error value that never gets greater than denominator+numerator-1.

Comment: to stay as close to the numerator/denominator ratio as possible after every call, the first next() should return true here, but it's false.

Answer (score 1):

```
//algorithm 
//1st call randomize(x) from main with x as percentage
//this calls fischershuffle to shuffle the boolean array
//den calls to return bool are randomized with x trues and 100-x falses per 100 calls

class A{
public static int count=0;
public static boolean fill[]=new boolean[100];

public static void randomize(double x)
{
double totaltrue=x*100;
double totalfalse=100-totaltrue;

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
if(totaltrue>0.00)
{
   fill[i]=true;
totaltrue-=1.00;
}
else
{
fill[i]=false;
totalfalse-=1.00;
}
}

fill=fischershuffle(fill);

}

static boolean fischershuffle(boolean[] ar)
  {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      boolean a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
    return ar;
  }


     public static boolean retunbool()
     {
      if(count<=100)
      {
     count++;
     return fill[count];
       }
     else{
     count=0;//resets after 100 for next 100 calls
    }
```

Comment: expanded on geobits answer

Comment: Just to let you know, my comment was based on an incorrect assumption, so this answer doesn't really solve the problem in the way it was intended.